# Add a key to my dictionary if condition is met

Tags: dictionary, for-loop

I have a very simple dictionary with three items.
I want to iterate through the dictionary and add a new item to it IF a condition is met. In this case, if the key "green" pops up.
I've been trying for a while and can't seem to figure it out. I keep getting ***"RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"***

My code :

```
color_dict = {"red" : "color", "green" : "color" , "three" : "not color"}

for i in color_dict:
    if i == "green":
        color_dict.update({"blue" : "color"})
```

I'm a beginner so I may not know the more advanced methods. Can someone help me with a simple fix? I feel like i'm missing something small but important.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```py
color_dict.update({"blue" : "color"})
```

with the following line

```py
color_dict['blue'] = 'color'
```

It works after this change.

As to why your code may not be working, it's because the `update()` method for a dictionary can only update values of keys already existing in the dictionary. For example, you could update the value of `three`:

```py
color_dict.update({"three" : "color"})
```

**OUTPUT :**

```py
>>> color_dict
{'red': 'color', 'green': 'color', 'three': 'not color', 'blue': 'color'}
```